# docker: unable to copy paste from the application

Tags: docker, ubuntu-20.04, amazon-workspaces

I am running aws workspace client inside a container

It can open my workspace and do all the work. But not able to copy paste text in and out.

Whereas if i install the aws workspace on my pc. I can do the copy paste

here is the aws workspace client container code

https://gist.github.com/mausch/168d09d18e354c8e47981b8e44746af9

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -eu

dockerfile=$(mktemp)
trap "rm $dockerfile" EXIT
cat << EOF > $dockerfile
FROM ubuntu:bionic

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget gnupg2

# https://clients.amazonworkspaces.com/linux-install.html
RUN wget -q -O - https://workspaces-client-linux-public-key.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ADB332E7.asc | apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://d3nt0h4h6pmmc4.cloudfront.net/ubuntu bionic main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/amazon-workspaces-clients.list 
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y workspacesclient
CMD /opt/workspacesclient/workspacesclient
EOF

docker build -t aws-workspaces - < $dockerfile
xhost +
docker run -it --rm --name aws-workspaces \
  -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix \
  -v "$HOME/.aws-workspaces":"/root/.local/share/Amazon Web Services" \
  -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY \
  aws-workspaces
```

Where if i install as per https://clients.amazonworkspaces.com/linux-install on my pc i am able to copy paste text in and out

I am using ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Why are you running a remote desktop client inside an isolation system; isn't the remote desktop enough isolation?  Is there some possibility that, when you completely disable X security in the second-to-last line, an attacker is connecting to your display and causing problems?

Comment: but the question is about the copy paste not working...

Comment: That seems like a problem in your desktop environment setup, not necessarily a programming question _per se_, especially if you're not running any of your own source code.  A Docker container doesn't have "a clipboard" as a concept.

Comment: thanks. definitely not related to programming thing. just wanted to know from docker perspective.